# How do I maximize this system of equations given the initial conditions?

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations

I am playing a semi-popular online game called Rust. In this game you must "craft" items given some supplies. Some items take multiple different items, that also must be crafted.

In my example I would like to maximize the equation

$$ E = 5M + 10G + 5S $$

Where $G$ is defined by

$$ G = 3C + 2S $$

And I initially have

$$ M = 36000, S = 17000, C=60000 $$

Notice my "issue" is that $S$ is within both equations, forming what I think is a system of linear equations.

**How do I go about maximizing $E$ in this case?**

Comment: There is not enough information to maximize the value of $E$ in this case. I could for example tell you to just let $M=\infty$ which would maximize $E$.

Comment: I'm guessing that's all the $M, S,$ and $C$ that you get for the game? If so, then the max $E$ you can make is when you use up all you can. The "limiting reagent" here is $S$, and you can make 680 E at most

Comment: It looks better to use your $S$ via $G$ if possible than directly.  So let $G=3\times 60000 + 2 \times 17000 = 214000$ and then $E=5 \times 36000+10 \times  214000 = 2320000$.  Though perhaps I have misunderstood your question and it really says that making one of $G$ consumes three of $3$ and two of $S$, and similarly one of $E$ consumes five of $M$ and ten of $E$ and five of $S$

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably trying to do is to maximize $E$ subject to the constraints $M \le 36000, S \le 17000, C \le 60000$.  You get $5$ points for each $M$, $10$ for each $G$, and $5$ for each $S$.  A $G$ comes from $3C+2S$.

The only question is how many $G$s to make and the only conflict is over $S$s.  You can either use $S$s by themselves, getting $5$ for each one, or make them part of $G$s, getting $10$ for two.  Here it doesn't matter, so just have $36000\ M$s and $17000\ S$s for $265000$.  Save the $C$s for another day.

It would be different if $G$s gave you more points per $S$ than $S$s did.  Now you would want to make all the $G$s you can until you run out of one material.  If you run out of $C$s, then keep the remaining $S$s.  In any case, use all the $M$s because there is no conflict for them.